# Replace all letters in a word with '*' after a certain word in a text file

Tags: text-processing, sed

I need to create a script that replaces all letters of a word after a certain word with an asterisk (`*`). 
For example:

```
sed 's/Word:[^ ]\+/Word:*/' Desktop/script_test
```

But this script replaces the entire word with only one asterisk, while I want to replace all letters. How can I do that?
For example, with this input:

```
Word: cat
```

I want to get

```
Word: ***
```

I am running Linux.

P.S. The input must be read from a text file and also saved to the same file.

Answer (score 4):

You could do it one at a time in a loop:

```
sed -e :1 -e 's/\(Word: *[^ ]*\)[^ *]/\1*/;t1'
```

To edit the file in place and assuming all the characters to replace are single-byte, you can make both sed's stdin and stdout  the file as in:

```
sed ... < file 1<> file
```

Or with GNU sed, use the `-i` flag as in:

```
sed -i ... file
```

(Though that will replace the file with a new one (though with the same name). With BSD sed, use `-i ''` instead of `-i`).

Comment: and, as a bonus, this will work with multiple `Word`s on the same line as opposed to most other solutions here...

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Are you using 2 separated `-e` in the `sed` command on purpose? Why not simply joining both: `-e ':1;s/\(Word: *[^ ]*\)[^ *]/\1*/;t1'`?

Comment: @oliv, in most `sed` implementations, `:1;s...` would define a label called `1;s...` instead of one called `1` followed by a `s` command (hence the need for two `-e`s). That even [used to be required by POSIX](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=945) making GNU `sed` (which honours the `;` as a command separator instead of being part of the label name even in POSIX mode) non-compliant then. POSIX still requires _you_ to not use `;` after the `:` command, but does not require anymore `sed` implementations to treat `;` as being part of the label name anymore.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
$ cat file
Word: cat
Word: foobar
$ sed -E 's/Word: *//; s/./*/g; s/^/Word: /' file
Word: ***
Word: ******
```

To modify the file in place, just use `-i`:

```
$ sed -E -i 's/Word: *//; s/./*/g; s/^/Word: /' file
```

Note that this won't work if `Word:` is not the first word of the line. If that's a problem, you can use this instead:

```
perl -pe 's/Word:\s*\K(\S+)/sprintf "*" x length($1)/e' file
```

That, in turn, assumes that you want the first `Word:` on each line and also that you want *everything* following it to be replaced by `*`. If you only want the first word after `Word:` to be replaced, you really should ask a new question or, at least, clarify this one.

Comment: This `sed` command has the drawback of expecting the keyword `Word: ` at the beginning of the line

Comment: @oliv well yes, of course it does. That's what the question is asking for isn't it?

Comment: That's not explicitly said... But don't worry, there is nothing wrong with your answer. I just came across this limitation and saw that the other `sed` command from @SatoKatsura was better suited for my own purpose.

Comment: @oliv all answers here except [the python one](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/346563/22222) where you can give `Word: ` as an option, including the one by Sato, require the presence of `Word:`. And it's mentioned very explicitly in the question as well. The whole point of the question is to replace only after `Word: `. Otherwise it would be just a trivial `sed 's/./*/g'`. It doesn't need to be at the beginning of the line, it just marks the position after which the substitution should occur.

Comment: Looks like you didn't get my point... Obviously the keyword is required to perform the replacement, but it is not said that this one must be at the _beginning_ of the line. Try it by putting any character before the keyword.

Comment: I have to agree with the criticism. IMO it’s clear from the question that an input of `foo bar` should be unchanged and an input of `Hello Word: Sailor` should be changed to `Hello Word: ******`, and I believe that `Word: cat food` is supposed to be changed to `Word: *** food`. Your answer fails on all three counts. Even *you* say, “… `Word:` … just marks the position after which the substitution should occur.” (If I’ve corrupted your meaning by excerpting, please explain what you mean.) Your answer doesn’t even do what you say it should (e.g., in the case of `Hello Word: Sailor`).

Comment: @oliv looks like I didn't get your point at all, no. I do now though, thanks! I added a perl version that can deal with `Word: ` not being at the beginning of the line. I am not going to also provide solutions for treating multiple words separately though, the OP can ask a new question for that. Anyway, thanks for pointing out the limitation and my apologies for taking so long to wake up to what you were trying to say.

Comment: @G-Man yep, see above. I had misunderstood oliv's original comment.

Comment: Slightly simpler `perl` solution: `perl -i -pe 's/Word:\s*\K\S+/"*" x length($&)/ge' file`

Answer (score 1):

An `awk` solution and a shell solution:

```
echo '"Hello: World"' | awk '{ gsub("[^\"]", "*", $2); print }'
```

We have to escape the `"` in `[^\"]` since the regular expression itself is in double quotes.  This generates

```
"Hello: *****"
```

With the shell (at least `bash` and `ksh93`):

```
echo '"Hello: World"' | {
  read -r prefix rest
  printf '%s %s\n' "$prefix" "${rest//[^\"]/*}"
}
```

Assuming the text `"Hello: World"` is on a line of its own, but embedded in a larger text in the file `greetings.txt`:

```
awk '/"Hello: [^"]*"/ { gsub("[^\"]", "*", $2) } { print }' greetings.txt >greet.tmp && mv greet.tmp greeting.txt
```

or (again, with `bash` or `ksh93`),

```
while read -r prefix rest; do
    if [[ "$prefix" =~ ^\"Hello: ]]; then
        rest=${rest//[^\"]/*}
    fi
    printf '%s %s\n' "$prefix" "$rest"
done <greetings.txt >greet.tmp
mv greet.tmp greetings.txt
```

For the input

```
Specific recipients:
"Hello: Mom!"
"Hello: Cat!"

General recipients:
"Hello: World!"
```

these two solutions generate

```
Specific recipients:
"Hello: ****"
"Hello: ****"

General recipients:
"Hello: ******"
```

Comment: The shell solution requires `=~` as found e.g. in `bash`.

Comment: @phk I failed to mention that, yes. I will add this.

Comment: The question says, “replace[s] all letters of a word ***after a certain word***”.  Your first answer will modify the *second* word of every line.  Your second answer will modify the *second **and all following words*** of every line. Also, your second and third answers will replace spaces after the second word, although the question indicates that spaces should not be replaced, and all your answers leave quote (`"`) characters unchanged, with no obvious justification.    … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … All your answers mangle spaces that aren’t replaced. Your third answer at least checks a preceding word, but (a) works only if the key word is the first word on the line (so it fails on `I said, "Hello: World"`), (b) requires that the `Hello` be preceded by a quote, with an equal absence of obvious justification, and (c) will match `"Hello:;,./ World"`.

Comment: @G-man My answer was to a version of the question that specified changing `"Word: cat"` into `"Word: ***"`. That's where the double quotes comes from. I also only have the data provided by the OP, so I (we) don't actually know in what context this is found (by itself, or part of a line).

Comment: @G-Man The first two solutions are for the single line given as input. Nothing else.

Comment: OK, sorry; I didn't look at the revision history of the question.

Answer (score 1):

You could to this using sed as follows:

```
echo 'Word: cat' |
sed -e '
   s/Word:/&\n/
   :loop
      s/\n\([^a-zA-Z]*\)[a-zA-Z]/\1*\n/
   tloop
   s/\n\([^a-zA-Z]*\)$/\1/
'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this time employing the hold space for manipulations, as:

```
sed -e '
   s/Word:/&\n/   # everything to the right of marker is asterisk zone
   h              # will need later on for reconstructing, so save orig
   s/.*\n//       # retain only the asterisk zone
   s/[a-zA-Z]/*/g # perform the asterisk operation
   H;g            # abut onto original data
   s/\n.*\n//     # peel off unwanted data
'
```

Comment: The question says, “replace[s] all letters of ***a word** after a certain word*”.  Your answer will modify ***all the words*** after the designated word (although, on the plus side, it doesn’t change the spaces between those words); also, it mangles lines that don’t even contain the trigger word.

Comment: Well this is what happens when the specs are very general. For example, what should we understand by a **word** ? Does it mean an English word or an alphanumeric a la `\w+` ? Normally for questions like these a varied input with the expected output must be give, whereas as you can see it's just Word: cat. No mention that Word: can be anywhere in a line, can be multiple times, or whatever. So your comments are better aimed at the OP to begin with IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

## Perl

```
echo 'Word: cat' |
perl -lpe '
   1 while s/(?<=Word:)([^a-zA-Z]*)([a-zA-Z]+)/$1 . "*" x length($2)/e;
'
```

## Bash

```
eval "`echo 'NL=qsq' | tr 'qs' '\047\012'`"; # newline
echo 'Word: cat' |
while IFS= read -r line
do
   var=${line/Word:/Word:"$NL"}
   var1=${var#*"$NL"}     var2=${var%"$NL"*}
   var3=${var1//[a-zA-Z]/*}
   var4=${var2}${var3}
   printf '%s\n' "$line" "$var4"
done
```

Comment: Simpler `perl`: `echo 'Word: cat' | perl -lpe 's/Word: \K.*/"*" x length($&)/e'`

Comment: Please don't post separate answers for each variant you come up with. just include them in your original answer.

Answer (score 1):

Python solution with more flexible command-line arguments:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys, fileinput

def replace_after(haystack, needle, replacement):
    pos = haystack.find(needle)
    if pos >= 0:
        pos += len(needle)
        return haystack[:pos] + (replacement * (len(haystack) - pos))
    else:
        return haystack

if __name__ == '__main__':
    needle, replacement = sys.argv[1:3]
    del sys.argv[1:3]

    with fileinput.input() as finput:
        for line in finput:
            print(replace_after(line.rstrip('\n'), needle, replacement))
```

Usage:

```
python3 unix.se.346510.py <NEEDLE> <REPLACEMENT> [FILES...]
```

Example:

```
$ printf '%s\n' 'Word: foo' 'more Word: bar-baz' | python3 unix.se.346510.py 'Word: ' '*'
Word: ***
more Word: *******
```

Answer (score 1):

Stuff like this goes better with flex:

```
%option 8bit main
%s star
%%
Word:           ECHO;  BEGIN star;
<star>[^ \t\n]+ memset(yytext,'*',yyleng); ECHO; BEGIN 0;
```

put that in say `star.l`, then `make star`.

(edit: states are vast overkill for this. better:

```
%option 8bit main
%%
Word:[^ \t\n]* memset(yytext+5,'*',yyleng-5); ECHO;
```

)

Answer (score 0):

Using awk, you don't mention, specific use of sed :)

> echo "Word: cat" | awk '{printf $1" "; for (i=1;i<=length($2);i++) printf "*"}'

Result:

> Word: ***

Comment: The question says, “replace[s] all letters of a word ***after a certain word***”. This code will modify the *second* word of every line; e.g., `fat cat` → `fat ***`. Also, this code will change `Here is the word: cat` to `Here **`.