# Replace a series of characters with an equal number of characters

Tags: sed

I want to replace strings which contain tilde character of varying lengths with strings of spaces. For example, if a string contains 5 tilde characters: `~~~~~`, then I want to replace it with 5 spaces.

My current `sed` command:

`sed -e '/\\begin{alltt}/,/\\end{alltt}/s/~\+/ /' test.tex`

I can check for one or more tilde characters, but don't know how to retrieve the length to insert the spaces

Comment: Refer this [link](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/346510/replace-all-letters-in-a-word-to-after-certain-word-in-text-file) , it might be of help.

Comment: Is `s/~/ /g` not an option? Or do you need to replace only the first sequence of `~`s on a line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sed '/\\begin{alltt}/,/\\end{alltt}/s/~/ /g'
```

Would replace all the `~`s with spaces. If you wanted to replace only the `~`s from the first sequence of `~`s on each line, you could do:

```
sed '
  /\\begin{alltt}/,/\\end{alltt}/{
    /~/ {
      h; # save a copy
      s/\(~\{1,\}\).*/\1/; # remove everything after the first sequence of ~s
      s/~/ /g; # replace ~s with spaces
      G; # append the saved copy
      s/\n[^~]*~*//; # retain only what's past the first sequence of ~s
                     # from the copy
    }
  }'
```

Note: `\{1,\}` is the standard equivalent of your `\+` GNU extension.

It's easier with `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's{~+}{$& =~ s/~/ /gr}e if /\\begin\{alltt\}/ .. /\\end\{alttt\}/'
```

or:

```
perl -pe 's{~+}{" " x length$&}e if /\\begin\{alltt\}/ .. /\\end\{alttt\}/'
```

Comment: Oh yes. It should be `~`, not `~\+` that matches the whole thing to be replaced.